# Form Input Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, web

Okay, I've been going through Google and tried different codes but they weren't really the ones i need. So here's my problem, i have a JavaScript that validates my input fields. It works great but the only problem is in the website field. I want it to check if the the value inside the input box contains ".com" at the end otherwise if will result an error. Please anyone can help me with this? Just need to know the how to go with the missing statement.. Here's my code..

```
var website=document.forms["reg"]["site"].value;
if (website==null || website=="")
{
    alert("Website field must be filled out");
    return false;
}
```

So as you can see, it will show an error if the value is empty. So as stated above, what do i put to check if ".com" must exist in the value of the input box.

Answer (score 0):

use the test method from Regexp object

something like:

`siteRE=/.com$/;

siteRE.test(inputValue);`

That returns a boolean telling you if it passed. Add i to end of the regex for case insensitive.

More info here....
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions to check if a string is part of your value.
Your test can look like this:

```
if (website.indexOf('.com') != -1) {
...
```

If you want to use regular expressions, make sure it's correct.
`/\.com/.test(website)` will test for presence of '.com' and `/\.com$/.test(website)` will test that your value is at the end of website.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. :) Unfortunately I tried implementing the website.indexOf but the error doesnt show up. how do i use the regular expresion? how do i implement it?